# Swift: UITableView does not update data properly using reload()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reload, uialertaction

I have a 30ish lang table divided 4 sections..

My problem is that, when i want to change the an value in one of the cells, the value doesn't update/change until I scroll that cell out of view and back in..

I use a UIAlert, to enter the new value, a save it to a DB.. And the value is saved alright, and i get the right value back again from the DB..

But when i reload the `tableView` it doesn't show the new value..

**Bouns:** I have two tableView one named: `templateTableView` and one named: `fieldTableView`. `fieldTableView` is the one i'm trying to change the values in. And changing `tableView.reload()` to `self!.fieldTableView.reload()` doesn't work either.

From didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
}else if currTemplate!.hasPassFail{
            var alertController:UIAlertController?
            alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter new value",
                message: "Enter new value",
                preferredStyle: .Alert)

            alertController!.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(
                {(textField: UITextField!) in
                    textField.placeholder = ""
                    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation
            })

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit",
                style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
                handler: {[weak self]
                    (paramAction:UIAlertAction!) in
                    if let textFields = alertController?.textFields{
                        let theTextFields = textFields as! [UITextField]
                        let enteredText = theTextFields[0].text
                        //what to do after edit, here:
                        switch indexPath.section{
                        case 1:
                            if let value = enteredText.toInt(){
                                self!.currTemplate!.backgroundMin[indexPath.row] = value
                            }else{
                                self!.presentViewController(self!.wrongNumberAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                return
                            }
                        case 2:
                            if let value = enteredText.toInt(){
                                self!.currTemplate!.legendMin[indexPath.row] = value
                            }else{
                                self!.presentViewController(self!.wrongNumberAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                return
                            }
                        case 3:
                            if let value = enteredText.toDouble(){
                                self!.currTemplate!.ratioMin[indexPath.row] = value
                            }else{
                                self!.presentViewController(self!.wrongNumberAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                return
                            }
                        default:
                            0-0
                        }
                        var date = NSDate()
                        self!.currTemplate!.timestamp = date.makeTimestampString()
                        self!.appDelegate.dbInterface.updateTemplate(self!.currTemplate!)
                        //self!.templateArr = self!.appDelegate.dbInterface.findTemplates()
                        self!.findAllNotDeleteOnSync()
                        println("Data was added to DB: \(self!.currTemplate!.ratioMin[indexPath.row])")
                        self!.templateTableView.reloadData()
                        self!.templateTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(self!.currentTemplateIndex, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                            tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                    }
                })
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            alertController?.addAction(cancel)
            alertController?.addAction(action)
            self.presentViewController(alertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

**Edit**
The part of the code that should have worked is this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
   tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you connected tableviews in storyboard or initialized it correctly?

Comment: Yes 
`@IBOutlet weak var templateTableView: UITableView!`
`@IBOutlet weak var fieldTableView: UITableView!`

Comment: r u properly getting indexpath of uitableviewcell which is being edited??

Comment: I've never seen this mysterious "self!" ...

Comment: @iAnurag Yep i'm positive.

Comment: Please explain to me

Comment: @Poql No, but thats have xcode/swift wants it.. :S

Comment: @Poql the "Yep i'm positive" was to iAnurag

Comment: Why do you this "[weak self]" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87781/discussion-between-bjqn-and-poql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causing malfunction

```
if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1
```

see carefully what you r writing in this condition
you are appending data only ablove condition satisfies
however in this case in your `didselectrowatindexpath`

```
case 3: 
if let value = enteredText.toDouble(){ 
self!.currTemplate!.ratioMin[indexPath.row] = value 
}else{ 
self!.presentViewController(self!.wrongNumberAlert, animated: true, completion: nil) 
return 
}
```

it get fails
thats why no data is getting appended when u r editing row in section 2 & 3
move appending code somewhere else
or use `if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1` this condition sectionwise

Comment: Thanks a ton.. i moved the appending part out to a separate func, and called that before `reload()` the table

Look at the char [HERE](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87781/discussion-between-bjqn-and-poql) for the more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    // do DB stuff in background thread
    // ...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Update UI in main thread when done
        // ...
    })
})
```

Comment: Nope, i still have to scroll, so that the cell with the changede value is out of the screen, and then back down to get the new value to show.. :S

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: That is exactly what i have done. And as i said in the text that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Update UI in main thread when done
        tableView.reloadData()
    })
})
```